# How select only ultimate value by month and business area?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the table below and I would like select only the last month according business area.

These original table:

```
fk_month    fk_business_area
201706       8
201707       25
201707       27
201707       9
201707       8
201707       28
201707       26
201708       9
```

After select, I want this result:

```
fk_month    fk_business_area
201707      25
201707      27
201707      8
201707      28
201707      26
201708      9
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siyual answer is the right way for this but if you have any other column apart from the ones mentioned then use `Row_Number` window function

```
select top 1 with ties *
from yourtable 
order by row_number()over(partition by fk_business_area order by fk_month desc)
```

Comment: This is going to be relatively slower compared to Siyual answer with `ROW_NUMBER()` because this will sort table once more compared to `RN = 1` filter.

Answer (score 5):

You could just do a `MAX()` aggregate:

```
Select   Max(fk_month) As fk_month,
         fk_business_area
From     TheseOriginalTable
Group By fk_business_area
```

You could also use a windowed function to find the most recent one:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By fk_business_area Order By fk_month Desc) RN
    From    TheseOriginalTable
)
Select  fk_month, fk_business_area
From    Cte
Where   RN = 1
```